# Right way to publish authors on PyPi from setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I currently use `setuptools` to build my Python's package and I have declared the two authors that way in my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
authors = [
     {name = "X Y", email = "x.y@tt.net"},
     {name = "Z H", email = "z.h@tt.net"},
]
```

Everything works and I can publish it on PyPI but only the first author is published. How can I display both authors.

I have tried to use the following syntax

```
authors = ["X Y <x.y@tt.net>, Z H <z.h@tt.net>"]
```

But I have the following error

```
ValueError: invalid pyproject.toml config: `project.authors[{data__authors_x}]`.
configuration error: `project.authors[{data__authors_x}]` must be object
```

Notice that I specify:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools","numpy","scipy","wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original notation is the correct one:

```
authors = [
     {name = "X Y", email = "x.y@tt.net"},
     {name = "Z H", email = "z.h@tt.net"},
]
```

but there are some issues that are out of your control.

On one hand it is not entirely clear how this should translate into the *Core Metadata* notation, which is the notation used inside the distribution artifacts (wheel), and which is then extracted and displayed by *PyPI*.

On the other hand, the build back-ends (`setuptools` included) are not explicit about how they transform from `pyproject.toml` notation to *Core Metadata* notation, and they tend to silently pick the first item of the list and ignore the following ones.

***References***:

- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#authors-maintainers
- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#author
- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#author-email
- https://discuss.python.org/t/the-author-maintainer-distinction-problem-and-pep-621/4562
- https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-621-round-3/5472/72
- https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-621-round-3/5472/86
- https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-621-round-3/5472/91