# importlib.metadata doesn't appear to handle the authors field from a pyproject.toml file correctly

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, python-importlib

I'm having a problem retrieving the author metadata information of a package through [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/importlib.metadata.html).

My package setup is as follows:

I'm using Python's `setuptools` with a minimal `setup.py` and some project metadata in `pyproject.toml`.

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

`pyproject.toml`:

```
[project]
name = "myproj"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Some description"
authors = [
    {name = "Some One", email = "some.one@example.com"},
    {name = "Another Person", email = "another.person@example.com"}
]
readme = "README.md"

requires-python = ">=3.11"
license = {text = "BSD-3-Clause"}

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

(I think `setup.py` is not even necessary for this, but for completeness.)

The `pyproject.toml` follows keywords described in [the Python packaging user guide - Declaring project metadata](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/).

The project itself is very simple: it's structure is

```
myproj/
       __init__.py
```

and in `myproj/__init__.py`, I'm using `importlib.metadata` to get some metadata information about the package.:

```
from importlib.metadata import metadata

meta = metadata(__package__ or __name__)
print(meta['Name'])
print(meta['Version'])
print(meta['Author-email'])
print(meta['Author'])
```

I install the package in a virtualenv using `pip`.

Outside of the project directory, but with the virtualenv activated, I run Python and import the package:

```
python -c "import myproj"
```

This prints the various metadata fields:

```
myproj
0.1.0
Some One <some.one@example.com>, Another Person <another.person@example.com>
None
```

This is where the problem is: the "Author-email" field yields the full `[project.authors]` entry, as a single string, while the "Author" field yields `None`.

Is there a way to get the individual authors (without their email) out of the metadata from within the package?

Or is `importlib.metadata` not up to date with the packaging metadata? (I did a quick search on bugs.python.org, but couldn't find anything related.)

(Of course, I can parse the "Author-email" field manually and separate it into appropriate parts, but it would be nice if that can be avoided.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the "author" and "author email" fields in Python packaging metadata:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75361691

---

If I were you I would look into [Python's own *`email`* library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html). There is a good chance it has the necessary features to parse the authors metadata properly.

It seems like something like the following could help (modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608484)):

```py
import email.policy

addresses = 'Some One <some.one@example.com>, Another Person <another.person@example.com>'

em = email.message_from_string(
    f'To: {addresses}',
    policy=email.policy.default,
)

for address in em['to'].addresses:
    print(f'{address.display_name} <{address.addr_spec}>')
```

Comment: Thanks. The linked answer indicates that this is then a (Core) metadata issue within Python packaging. As for the author parsing: I went for splitting on the comma (but someone better not have a name or email address with a comma), then stripping of the `>` and splitting on the last `<`. Not the best solution, but I guess no solutions for getting proper detailed author info out of the metadata is neat.

Comment: Use the sample code from my answer, it works perfectly and is entirely reliable, no surprise.